# Tooling API SOQL Where clause not working for certain fields

Tags: soql, tooling-api, where

I'm working in the developer console using the tooling api to write a query against permission sets.

This query works:

```
select Name, Label, Description, ManageableState, NamespacePrefix, Type from PermissionSet
```

but this query returns 0 rows (where the query above showed many that were 'unmanaged'):

```
select Name, Label, Description, ManageableState, NamespacePrefix, Type from PermissionSet 
where ManageableState = 'unmanaged'
```

This query returns ALL the rows, including those where manageablestate is 'Installed'

```
select Name, Label, Description, ManageableState, NamespacePrefix, Type from PermissionSet 
where ManageableState != 'installed'
```

I'm having the same results if I try to use the Type field in the where clause.

Any idea why I can't get it to filter on these two fields?  It doesn't give me any error, the query runs and just returns the wrong results.

Comment: that's really weird, even in the official doc it is written, that this filter property is allowed. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_permissionset.htm

Comment: Right?  I have a where clause on the ManageableState field in other queries and it works (also against the Tooling API) but not on this one.  I was assuming I must be doing something wrong or missing something simple but maybe not?

Comment: yeah, maybe you can submit a case to get it verified.